# How to define the function $f(t)=\begin{cases} 2 & ,0 \leq t \leq 2 \\ -1 & ,2 \leq t \leq 3 \end{cases}$ with the Heaviside step function?

Tags: calculus, functions

I had this problem, I know that 
$u(t-a):=\begin{cases} 0 & ,0 \leq t \leq a \\ 1 & , t \geq a \end{cases}$
and a piecewise function $f(t)=\begin{cases} g(t) & ,0 \leq t \leq a \\ h(t) & , t \geq a \end{cases}$ can be written in the form $f(t)=g(t)-g(t)u(t-a)+h(t)u(t-a)$.
How I can apply this to the first function $f(t)$. Can I apply also to the function 
$f(t)=\begin{cases} 2 &, 0 \leq t \leq 2 \\ -1 &, 2 \leq t \leq 3 \\ 0 &,t\geq3 \end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

Heaviside function is a function that change value by a constant after value $a$.

For your function, the first time, there is a change of value is at $0$, followed by $2$ and then followed by $3$.

Hence $$f(t) = bu(t-0)+ cu(t-2) + du(t-3)$$

The first jump is by $2$, hence $b=2$.

The next value drop by value $-3$, hence $c=-3$.

Can you determine the value of $d$?

Answer (score 1):

we know , $k .[u(t-a) - u(t-b)] $ denotes rectangular pulse from duration $\ a $ to$ \ \ b$  of height $k$ units   (assume $b>a$)

therefore,

$f(t)= 2 [u(t)-u(t-2)]-1[u(t-2)-u(t-3)]+0[u(t-3)]$

$ \implies 2 \ u(t)-3\ u(t-2) +u(t-3)  $